# d3.js Update data binding

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-binding

There are things I don't clearly understand about data binding in d3.js.

I have set up a simple example (that can be found [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MJKRER?editors=1010)) where 4 numbers are displayed:

```
var data0 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var data1 = [5, 6, 7,8];
var data2 = [10, 11,12];

var lgth = 100;
var wdth = 50;
var position = [[0,0],[0,wdth], [lgth,0],[lgth,wdth]];

var svg = d3.select("#test").append("svg")
            .attr("width", wdth+100)
            .attr("height", lgth+100);

svg.selectAll("text").data(data0)
      .enter().append("text")
      .text(function(d){return d;})
      .attr("x",function(d,i){return position[i][0]+30;})
      .attr("y",function(d,i){return position[i][1]+30;});
```

However when I try to update these 4 numbers using that function:

```
function draw1(){
svg.selectAll("text").data(data1)
      //.enter().append("text") /* if not commented does nothing*/
      .text(function(d){return d;})
      .attr("x",function(d,i){return position[i][0]+30;})
      .attr("y",function(d,i){return position[i][1]+30;});
}
```

it works only if `.enter().append("text")` is commented. Why ? What if there are less data in the new binding than in the previous one ?

Thanks a lot in advance for the explanation !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  svg.selectAll("text").data(data0)
  .enter().append("text")
  .text(function(d){return d;})
  .attr("x",function(d,i){return position[i][0]+30;})
  .attr("y",function(d,i){return position[i][1]+30;});
```

*.enter().append("text")* will create new elements as needed. Here in this case both arrays *data0* and *data1* have same number of elements so there is no need of new text elements d3 will just update the values. Hence no need of *.enter().append("text")*

```
  svg.selectAll("text").data(data1)
  .text(function(d){return d;})
  .attr("x",function(d,i){return position[i][0]+30;})
  .attr("y",function(d,i){return position[i][1]+30;});
```

You should add the following line in draw1() for *exit* which will remove old elements(if there  is less data in new binding)

```
svg.selectAll("text").exit().remove()
```

I recommend you to refer the following example for understanding the process more clearly:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However even if the both data set are of the same length, shouldn't .enter().append("text") work as it did in the first place, and overwrite the text ? (which is not the case!)
I also added svg.selectAll("text").exit().remove() in a second function [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MJKRER?editors=1010) with a smaller data set and it does not remove the old element  ...

Comment: @Guillaume the moment you write `enter()` you have an enter selection, whose size is **zero** if the length of the data array is the same. Thus, `.enter().append("text")` will never work.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thanks for you comment. It's a bit clearer: it means that enter() is for  new element only. So, let say data1.length=5, meaning I have 4 texts to update and 1 to create. How can I achieve that ? If I do write enter(), it creates the fifth element but not upgrade the four others, and , conversely, if I do not write enter(), it updates the 4 texts but the fifth is not created ... exemple [here](http://jsbin.com/herikojeke/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: In that case, you need to set your update selection right. Have a look at this example I wrote in the Docs: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/d3.js/5749/update-pattern/20318/updating-the-data-a-basic-example-of-enter-update-and-exit-selections#t=201701121525116433209

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thanks a lot. I finally got it .. I had missed the merge() function. Thanks again.